# pause mediaelement when user switches to another app in windows 8 C# XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I had created mediaplayer using mediaelement in windows 8 C#,XAML.
Everything works fine.But there are critical questions I have  as follows.

1. User Navigates to the PlayerPage.
2. Player starts playing the media.
3. Now user moves his mouse to left corner and switches to the another app.

My Questions are as follows.

1. **How do I pause my mediaelement if user is switches to the another app?**
2. **If user presses windowsbutton + L the device goes in lock state How do I pause the mediaelement?**
3. **User presses only windowsbutton How do i pause the mediaelement?**

Please give any suggestions/guidance so that I can complete my player.

Comment: actually I think this should be default behavior if you will not enable background media capability. Did you try this? Do you have enabled this capability?

Answer (score 0):

In constructor assign this event. It will be called when your app's visibility gets collapsed.

```
Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().VisibilityChanged += MyPlayer_VisibilityChanged;
```

Here's event body.

```
async void MyPlayer_VisibilityChanged(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.VisibilityChangedEventArgs args)
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        //TODO : First get args.Visible property. If it's false & media is playing, just pause it.
    });
}
```